# Getting last two values emitted from a chained Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two Observables that I am trying to chain together.  I need to subscribe to both and act on the emitted values for both.  I feel like I'm doing something wrong in my setup and wanted to ask if this is the best way to accomplish this.

Essentially I have one Observable that is emitting values from a stream.  In the second value, I want the last two values emitted from the first Observable.  This is because if the first Observable throws an error, I need to know what the response was right before the error was thrown.

In addition, I want these to execute in order, so if the `first` observable emits:

`[0, 1, 2, <error>]`

My console should read:

```
0
1
2
Notification[2] (where the first element is 2 and the second is the error notification
```

Here is what I have:

```
const first = interval(1000).pipe(take(5));

source.subscribe({
  next(response) {
    console.log("First: ", response);

    // Process the response
    // .......
  }
});


// Create a second Observable from the first that only emits the last two messages
// from the first Observable
const second = first.pipe(materialize(), bufferCount(2), last());

second.subscribe({
  next(response) {
    console.log("Second: ", response);
  }
});
```

Is this the easiest way to subscribe to two chained Observables?  I'm assuming I could use a `flatMap` or `concat` here somewhere, but I have two Observables of different types, so I'm not sure how that would work.  I think I'm most bothered by how I have two subscriptions here to related observables.

Comment: Not my area of expertise but could you stash the response in a variable (outside the handler) at the end of each event so you’d be able to access it if necessary on the next call?

Comment: What is `source` in your example?

Comment: `source` is an observable wrapping a grpc-web stream.  So as responses are sent to the client, they are emitted to subscribers of `source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An `RxJS#Observable` has 3 types of emissions.

1. **next** : An observable can have any number of `next` emissions. This means an observable with 0 emissions is completely fine. The emission itself comes with a value. If you're using TypeScript, the type of this value is encoded in the type of the Observable. A stream that emits a number:
   `const stream: Observable<number> = of(42);`

2. **complete** : An observable can only ever send 1 `complete` emission. After this emission the observable is done and will never emit anything else again. The emission itself doesn't have a value.
3. **error** : This is the exact same as complete, only it does have a value. Typically the value is an error message or object (hence the name of this emission). If you're using TypeScript, the type of this value isn't encoded in the type of the Observable (Similar to how a function `throw`s an error). Remember that *(like complete)* after this emission the observable is done and will never emit anything else ever again.

---

### Remembering the last value before an error

There are many approaches to this. Consider this:

```ts
// Emit next once per sceond
const a$ = interval(1000);
// Never emits a next, emits an error after 5.5seconds
const b$ = timer(5500).pipe(
  tap(_ => {throw "This is an error"})
);

merge(a$, b$).subscribe({
  next: value => console.log("next: ", value),
  complete: () => console.log("terminal emission (complete)"),
  error: e => console.log("terminal emission (error): ", e)
});
```

Output:

```html
next:  0
next:  1
next:  2
next:  3
next:  4
terminal emission (error):  This is an error
```

An error is a terminal emission just like complete, but most operators act in such a way that they error themselves with an error emission arrives. So `takeLast(2)` waits for a `complete` emission and will error itself if it receives an `error` emission.

You can turn an error into another stream using `catchError`. If you choose a stream that `completes` rather than `errors` you can get back into more usual behaviour.

**Solution** I've created a custom operator that does what you've described (I think). It leaves the source observable untouched unless it throws an error. It rethrows the same error, but with a `previousValue` added in. Here it is in use:

```ts
// Custom operator that will embelish any error thrown with the last
// cached value emitted. lastValue = null if error is thrown before
// any values are emitted.
function embelishErrors<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    let cache: T | null = null;
    return s.pipe(
      tap(v => cache = v),
      catchError(e => throwError(() => ({
        lastValue: cache, 
        error: e
      })))
    );
  })
}

// Emit next once per sceond
const a$ = interval(1000);
// Never emits a next, emits an error after 5.5seconds
const b$ = timer(5500).pipe(
  tap(_ => {throw "This is an error"})
);

merge(a$, b$).pipe(
  embelishErrors()
).subscribe({
  next: value => console.log("next: ", value),
  complete: () => console.log("terminal emission (complete)"),
  error: e => console.log("terminal emission (error): ", e)
});
```

Output:

```html
next:  0
next:  1
next:  2
next:  3
next:  4
terminal emission (error):  { lastValue: 4, error: 'This is an error' }
```

Comment: In the `takeLast(2)` case, when `This is an error` occurs, I would like to have access to the previous value (i.e. `4`).  Is that possible in this example?  Not seeing it there, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @sma sure, you can transduce into an array. I've updated my example.

Comment: Awesome.  One additional question.  I would expect the output to print `[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, This is an error]` or similar.  Since the first observable starts 4.5 seconds before the second, why do we not see a few emissions from there?

Comment: @sma I think I'm starting to see what you're after. Does this newest update look better? It leaves the original source undisturbed and just embellishes errors with a previous value.

Comment: Yes!  This works, thank you @Mrk Sef

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { takeLast } from 'rxjs/operators';

const firstSource$ = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'error-message');
const secondSource$ = firstSource$.pipe(
 takeLast(2) // take the last 2 values 
);

secondSource$.subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
// output: 
// 5
// 'error-message'
```

Comment: This solution assumes the error would be emitted as a `next` value to the subscription. If it's emitted as an `error`, the subscription would only trigger the `error` callback, which at the moment isn't present in the solution.